# cx_Freeze not found error-python

Tags: python-3.x

Ok, I am using python 3.4.3 and I think I downloaded the right file but when I go to python shell, it says No module named 'cx_Freeze'

I know there are plenty of questions like this but none of them helped. There was one I found using my exact same problem and version but even that did not work. I do not know what to do. I have put the file in the same place, I think anyways, as python is and I tried putting it on my desktop but still does not work. Any ideas?

Answer (score 0):

faced a similar problem (Python 3.4 32-bit, on Windows 7 64-bit). After installation of cx_freeze, three files appeared in c:\Python34\Scripts:

cxfreeze
cxfreeze-postinstall
cxfreeze-quickstart
These files have no file extensions, but appear to be Python scripts. When you run python.exe cxfreeze-postinstall from the command prompt, two batch files are being created in the Python scripts directory:

cxfreeze.bat
cxfreeze-quickstart.bat
From that moment on, you should be able to run cx_freeze.

cx_freeze was installed using the provided win32 installer (cx_Freeze-4.3.3.win32-py3.4.exe). Installing it using pip gave exactly the same result.

Comment: Wait, I am so confused. You want me to do what? Type that into cmd or startmenue or python shell? What? You mean I have to move files? Confused here.

Answer (score 0):

Ok, I figured it out. So this is for all the future people have the same problem as I am. First, download pip. Then open a python shell and import pip. This is to make sure the download of pip was successful. Then go to the cx_Freeze website and for python 3.4.3, it will be the last one I think. It will say the version of cx_Freeze and then say the version of python which is 3.4.3 for me. That will download and then go to python shell and import cx_Freeze. It should work. Remember that you have to capitalize the "F" and have the code be exactly like this "cx_Freeze" but without the quotes. That is how I solved this problem with this exact python version.